# Please add [system-programming] as a synonym of [systems-programming] (or vice-versa)

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

These tags are far from being populated enough to permit any *muggle* from changing them.

So, from [system-programming](/questions/tagged/system-programming) to [systems-programming](/questions/tagged/systems-programming), please.

Comment: To downvoter: Care to explain? Are they somehow not synonyms, or is this about the request for a manual synonym itself?

Comment: I think adding `systems-programming` as a synonym of `system-programming` would be better.

Comment: @Nyu Which ever works best, I'm fine with it.